# How to test if user is on the mainnet/testnet using web3?

Tags: web3js, rinkeby, react, networkid

Hello everyone I need your quick help!

I am using web3 1.0.0-beta.34 with React and Next.js and I want to check if user has it Metamask set on mainnet/rinkeby network.

I have read quite a few solutions but I am having a slight problem implementing them.

Basically, I have a Layout component which serves as a wrapper around all the elements, so it is called on every page.

What I found so far is this:

```
web3.eth.net.getId().then(netId => {
  switch (netId) {
    case 1:
      console.log('This is mainnet')
      break
    case 2:
      console.log('This is the ropsten test network.')
      break
    case 3:
      console.log('This is the kovantest network.')
      break
    case 4:
      console.log('This is the rinkeby network.')
      break
    default:
      console.log('This is an unknown network.')
  }
})
```

I don't want to console.log it, I want to put it in some kind of a variable, but I am not able to use React state. To simplify it, all I want from this function is to return me a number/string ID of the network where the user is at the moment. For now, it is only returning me a Promise object, and I don't know how to extract the ID from it.

```
var net = web3.eth.net.getId();
console.log(net);
```

this is what it shows

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__:Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]:1
```

What i really need is this [[Promise Value]] extracted to a const/var so that I can manipulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a question about developing in Javascript in general, so next time I suggest to use another proper channel for this kind of question.

With Web3 you are actually executing **async calls**.

You have two methods to get result from async calls in Javascript: **Callbacks** (the old fashioned method, always present) and **Promises** (a newer and cleaner method, still it is not already available in all JS libraries).

Here a full example for your case:

```
// Utility function
var showNetId = function (netId) {
    console.log("Network ID is", netId)
}

// Callback function: see that error are passed to the function as the first parameter, and the result is the second
var callbackExample = function (error, result) {
    if(error) console.err("There was an error during the call:", error)
    else showNetId(result)
}

// Please note this function is async because I use the "await" command inside
var examples = async function() {

    // To do something just after the promise is fullfilled
    web3.eth.net.getId().then(showNetId)

    // To get the promise and then do something, when the promise is fullfilled
    var promise = web3.eth.net.getId()
    promise.then(showNetId)

    // To get the promise and then, when the promise is fullfilled, assign a variable
    var netId = undefined;
    var promise = web3.eth.net.getId()
    await promise.then((result) => netId = result)
    showNetId(netId)

    // Blocking execution with "await" as if it was a sync call
    var result = await web3.eth.net.getId()
    showNetId(result)

    // Old fashioned callback
    web3.eth.net.getId(callbackExample)

}

examples();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store it into browser storage or cookies.